# Use of undeclared identifier 'UILocalNotification'

Tags: ios, xcode

Recently I have learned how to program a iOS project. I coded by followed a tutorial.But the same code the different result. Maybe there is something wrong with header file? I imported a header file in the same project.Although it made Xcode no warn about "use of undeclared identifier 'UILocalNotification' ", it did't make the effect that I want.And I want to say ,in the tutorial the teacher did't have imported this header file .So mistake must not be here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Judging by the error, it looks like you might have used a UILocalNotification somewhere in your code that you did not include the proper #import for.

What tutorial were you using? Is there a 'completed project' that they provide that you can compare your code to?

It might be helpful to include any relevant code (from your project) that will aid in the process of troubleshooting the error.

As a side note: Check  how recently the tutorial was written-- if it is an older one (for previous versions of XCode), you may need to alter, remove, or add some code in order to fix certain errors.

Comment: The tutorial is a completed project. I have downloaded the whole project from git. And it can be run in my Xcode. And I checked the code with the error file .the code are same .Actually I copied the code which is in the tutorial project to my project . The Xcode still warns. I think it must be wrong in my project somewhere.

Comment: If you would like, I would be happy to compare the two if you would upload your (error) project to github, and link me to it as well as the completed (tutorial) project. If the codes are indeed the same, then there may be a problem in your interface builder connections to your code.

Comment: my project:https://github.com/dwjdwj1216/Checklists                                       tutorial project:https://github.com/eseedo/kidscoding/tree/master/iOS%20Learning%202/source%20code/iOS%20入门%202/cha28(The%20End)                                  And thank you very much!

Comment: The link you provided for the tutorial project isn't working for me (there are chinese characters in the url that my browser can't use)

edit: never mind, I found the project myself

Comment: If I add #import<UIKit/UIKit.h> into the  ChecklistItem.h file, these errors disappear. In the tutorial project, if you click on the project file in xcode, and go into the checklist target, there are 3 linked frameworks and libraries which are not linked in your project. This might be the source of the problem, but I am not entirely sure.

Comment: I added the frameworks to your project, added the #import<UIKit/UIKit.h> into the ChecklistItem.h file, removed both test folders from your project / project targets, and changed your app's deployment target to 7.0 (instead of 9.0) . That seemed to get rid of every error, and your project is working perfectly! :~)

Comment: Thank you very much ! I will try it.

Comment: I bother why the checklistItem.h in tutorial project did't import <UIKit/UIkit.h> and there is no error.

Comment: I think it might have to do with the frameworks that were included the tutorial project. Try to remove the #import<UIKit/UIKit.h> from ChecklistItem file once you have those frameworks added and test it again.

Comment: it failed. I have added the frameworks already, but it seemed useless.But there is a 'XCTest.framework' which i can't find in my Xcode that i did't add.Is it the source of the problem?